# Which arguments for Golang decorator functions

Tags: go, interface, decorator

I would like to use a setter on several methods of AdminAPI such as `Update`. To do so I created a method type that could match with other methods.

Should I use interface instead of `func type`?

```
type AdminAPI struct {
}

type ToAdminCtx func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error)

func (a AdminAPI) AdminM2MSetter(s ToAdminCtx) ToAdminCtx {
    return func(ctx context.Context, arg interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        m2mPrincipal, _ := a.GetM2MPrincipal(ctx)
        ctxM2M := extlib.SetPrincipal(ctx, m2mPrincipal)
        return s(ctxM2M, arg)
    }
}

func (a AdminAPI) Update(ctx context.Context, req *ReqType) (RespType, error) {}
```

```
updateWithAdminCtx := a.adminAPI.AdminM2MSetter(s.adminAPI.Update)
// ERROR => cannot use s.adminAPI.Update (value of type func(ctx 
// context.Context, req *ReqType) (RespType, error)) as grpcAdmin.ToGetAdminCtx value in 
// argument to s.adminAPI.AdminM2MSetter

_, err := updateWithAdminCtx(ctx context.Context, req *ReqType)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is pretty self-explanatory I think:

```
a.adminAPI.AdminM2MSetter(s.adminAPI.Update)
```

This is calling

```
func (a AdminAPI) AdminM2MSetter(s ToAdminCtx) ToAdminCtx {
```

Passing in `s.adminAPI.Update` as the argument, which is expected to be of the type `ToAdminCtx`. That type you is defined as:

```
type ToAdminCtx func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

Yet your `Update` function's second argument is a `*ReqType`, and its first return value is a `RespType` value, and therefore `Update` is not a `ToAdminCtx`. The `ToAdminCtx` function type is a function that can be called with a context and **literally ANY type**. Your `Update` function cannot be guaranteed to work in all cases the `ToAdminCtx` function can.

What you're looking for is a way to *"wrap"* any function, add do some work on the `ctx` argument (probably setting some value), and then pass on the call. Before go 1.19, we did this by adding some kind of wrapper types like this:

```
type Wrapper struct {
    UpdateReqType *ReqType
    AnotherType *ReqType2 // for some other call you want to wrap
}
```

The change all the relevant functions, like your `Update` function to take the wrapper argument type:

```
func (a AdminAPI) Update(ctx context.Context, req Wrapper) (Resp, error) {
    realReq := req.UpdateReqType // get the actual request used here
}
```

The response types would either be similarly wrapped and/or composed.

Now, though, go supports generics, and this is a situation where they can be quite useful, let's change your `AdminM2MSetter` function to something like this:

```
func AdminM2MSetter[T any, R any](s func(context.Context, T) (R, error)) func(context.Context, T) (R, error) {
    return func (ctx context.Context, arg T) (R, error) {
        m2mPrincipal, _ := a.GetM2MPrincipal(ctx)
        ctxM2M := extlib.SetPrincipal(ctx, m2mPrincipal)
        return s(ctxM2M, arg)
    }
}
```

This way, we only have to define this function once, but rely on the compiler to generate a tailor-made function for all the types we need. In case of your `Update` function, we'd do something like this:

```
a.adminAPI.AdminM2MSetter[*ReqType, RespType](s.adminAPI.Update)
```

Essentially replacing the generic `T` and `R` types with the specific types used by your `Update` function. Because I don't really know what functions you want to wrap in this way, I used `T any, R any`, but because it looks to me like you're trying to wrap request handlers of some sort, you could create your own constraints:

```
type Requests interface {
    *ReqType1 | *ReqType2 | *ReqType3 // and so on
}
type Responses interface {
    Resp1 | Resp2 | Resp3
}
```

And just replace `[T any, R any]` with `[T Requests, R Responses]`

Comment: Thanks for all. However, the method AdminM2MSetter is not attached to a struct in what you are suggesting. When I attached it I get the error message : "method must have no type parameters"
I suppose that everything is in this doc....
https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#No-parameterized-methods

Comment: Instead of a receiver function, can't you just make it a normal function and pass in the type as an argument to `AdminM2MSetter` (being a regular function)?, The arguments then being just `a YourType, s funcType`. It's currently a receiver, so you have the type available